# How to call many results on Postman changing value in URL?

Tags: postman

I need to have many results but the API has only a GET method and give me results on-by-one, for example: api.edu/software/student/123-ABC

This json brings around 10 information about this student.

But 123-ABC is a enrollment, I have 5000 enrollments and I can't call one by one.
I need a way to put api.edu/software/student/{{enrollment}} and bring me a json with all the 5000 results.

I have a csv file with all the enrollment to be use if necessary.

Thanks all

Comment: You can use the postman collection runner feature - https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files/

Comment: Hi Wilfred Clement,

Thanks for the advice but isn't working. The postman isn't accepting .csv, not even the own example of .csv from the link you posted.